# PHP re-organizing an array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

The array has to be organized so that, rather than having each value in the array, the array values of arrays with the values of the data, and each of those nested arrays must have a max number of values.

So it should start with this:

```
$data = array(
  0 => 'Data 1',
  1 => 'Data 2',
  2 => 'Data 3',
  3 => 'Data 4',
  4 => 'Data 5',
  5 => 'Data 6',
);
```

and then given that `$max = 3;`, the array should become this:

```
$data = array(
  0 => array(
    0 => 'Data 1',
    1 => 'Data 2',
    2 => 'Data 3',
  ),
  1 => array(
    0 => 'Data 4',
    1 => 'Data 5',
    2 => 'Data 6',
  ),
);
```

I feel like I'm close, but I keep losing the fourth data value when my max is set to 3.

```
$max_col = 3;
$current_row = 0;
$current_col = 0;
foreach ($data_values as $val) {
  if ($current_col < $max_col) {
    $new_data[$current_row][$current_col] = $val;
    $current_col++;
  } else {
    $current_col = 0;
    $current_row++;
    $new_data[$current_row][$current_col] = $val;
  }
}
```

What I end up with is this:

```
$data = array(
  0 => array(
    0 => 'Data 1',
    1 => 'Data 2',
    2 => 'Data 3',
  ),
  1 => array(
    0 => 'Data 5',
    1 => 'Data 6',
  ),
);
```

Comment: Look at [array_chunk()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php)

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel, use Jonathan's answer. It makes the intention of the code clear and because it's a native function, it runs much faster than user code.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [array_chunk](http://www.php.net/array_chunk)

```
<?php
$data = array(
  0 => 'Data 1',
  1 => 'Data 2',
  2 => 'Data 3',
  3 => 'Data 4',
  4 => 'Data 5',
  5 => 'Data 6',
);

$newData = array_chunk($data, 3);

print_r($newData);
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Data 1
            [1] => Data 2
            [2] => Data 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Data 4
            [1] => Data 5
            [2] => Data 6
        )

)
```

http://codepad.viper-7.com/AwGZ5V

Answer (score 1):

Just increment $current_row at the end:

```
else {
    $current_col = 0;
    $new_data[$current_row][$current_col] = $val;
    $current_row++;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

your code is almost ok except a minor addition

```
 $max_col = 3;
 $current_row = 0;
 $current_col = 0;
 foreach ($data_values as $val) {
  if ($current_col < $max_col) {
    $new_data[$current_row][$current_col] = $val;
    $current_col++;
    } else {
      $current_col = 0;
      $current_row++;
      $new_data[$current_row][$current_col] = $val;
      $current_col++; //this is the new line you have to add
    }
```

}